# Как создать эффект переворота?

Tags: javascript, css

Написал эффект переворота на чистом `CSS` но никак не могу реализовать чтобы картинка **переворачивалась быстро несколько раз за секунду** потом 5 секунду неизменно стоял.Потом опять продолжалось.

```css
img {
    background: #00f;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    animation: rotate 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/c/c1/Thanosinfinity.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160119073257">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
   
 
img {
    background: #00f;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    animation: rotate 6s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 6s infinite;
}


@keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
  17% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% { transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
  17% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/c/c1/Thanosinfinity.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160119073257">
```

Наверное лучше поставить поворот на 720градусов 0% { transform: rotateY(720deg); } В общем, на ваш вкус.

Comment: понял в чем была загвоздка спасибо @Rustin

Answer (score 4):

Так?

```css
img {
    background: #00f;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    animation: rotate 6s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 6s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
      5% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
     10% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
     15% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
     20% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
@keyframes rotate {
      5% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
     10% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
     15% { transform: rotateY(180deg); }
     20% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/c/c1/Thanosinfinity.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160119073257">
```

Comment: нет у вас картинка слишком медленно переворачивается

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 360px;
  animation: flip 6s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: flip 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0); }
  16% { transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(1080deg); }
}
```